# change src of iframe and then reload the iframe

Tags: javascript, jquery

I managed to change an iframe's src with javascript

```
var path='images/tattoo/fullsize/';
var h=$('#borderlessFrame').height();
var bigFrame=$('#borderlessFrame');
function loadGallery(num)
{
    bigFrame=$('#borderlessFrame');
    var galPath=path + num;             // path to the image
    h=$('#borderlessFrame').height();
    var source=bigFrame.attr('src');
    source='i load some address here';
}
```

But for now i see the old content of the iframe , is there a way to reload the iframe ( only iframe not the whole page)
The thing i am trying to achieve is a simple gallery  , thumb pictures on the bottom and a large picture on the top ( iframe ). On click on any of the thumbs , i change the content of the iframe without reloading the actual page.

Keep in mind that i am new to html/javascript/jquery.
So basically i need a way(function?) to reload the iframe.

Comment: In 11 lines of code you managed to query for `'#borderlessFrame'` 4 times... Cache the reference please!

Comment: document.getElementById('calendar').src = loc;

Comment: I always thought if you changed the src it would reload the frame automatically?

Comment: @Jleagle it does, but he never actually changed the iframe's src.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

To set attribute, you need to call `.attr( attributeName, value )`

Try this:

```
var source='i load some address here';
bigFrame.attr('src', source);
```

### Reference:

[jQuery **.attr()**](http://api.jquery.com/attr/)

Comment: just out of curiosity doesnt this do the same thing
var source=bigFrame.attr('src');
    source='i load some address here';

Comment: OK , i answered my question , so i guess it doesn't do the same thing.
The code you provided worked , ty again.

Comment: well, read the link,

`.attr( attributeName )`
`Returns: String`
Its actually a "Get" function. It returns the attribute. you are assigning the src attribute to "source" variable. But the returned value is clone, not by reference attached to the attribute. So when you `source = 'some address';` it changes the source variable only, not linked to the iframe element.

and,

.attr( attributeName, value )
Description: Set one or more attributes for the set of matched elements

Its a set method. to its sets "attributeName" (here "src") of the element to the given value.

Comment: This does not reload the new source as the poster asked.  It only sets the iframe's attribute to the new source.

Comment: 2016 update: Nowadays you should use the `.prop()` method instead of `.attr()`.

Answer (score 8):

jQuery has [the `load` method](http://api.jquery.com/load/), which is useable like so (assuming `borderlessFrame` is the id of the `<iframe>`):

```
var iFrame = $('#borderlessFrame');
iFrame.load('http://theurltoload.com')
```

However, iframes seem like an unnecessary approach for your requirements, consider looking into CSS and the jQuery DOM manipulation methods a little more.