# iframe: How can we change iframe src from inside iframe itself?

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe

I know there are question have been asked around resembling to this one, but still I am not getting proper concept of this. I am currently loading an iframe through javascript in following manner:

```
jQuery('.out-div-login').html("<iframe id='parent' frameBorder='0' width='320' height='500' src='"+_url+"'></iframe>");
```

Which is working fine. (its cross domain). After loading my application inside given iframe, I want to come back to original state where `.out-div-login` was loading iframe into parent html.
From outside of iframe I can do this by accessing iframe using its `id` attribute, but not from the inside. Is there any way I can reload the iframe by giving its src again ? or by above code but from inside the iframe ? Thanks.
**Update**
I have tried below code without any success as of now:

```
var ifr = $('iframe[id="parent"]');
```

from one of js file inside `iframe` with id `parent`. when I do `console.log(ifr)` it gives in firebug something like this `Object[]` instead of `<iframe id="parent">`

Comment: possible duplicate of [change src of iframe and then reload the iframe](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8989247/change-src-of-iframe-and-then-reload-the-iframe)

Comment: @Sebi2020 Thanks for your response, but code in given link works only when we try to execute from outside iframe.!! I have tried this, I am not even able to get `iframe` reference from inside the current `iframe`

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You should use `location.href` inside the iframe. That should work. set location.href in the iframe to your new location.

Comment: So `location.href` target to current document !! for this iframe is current document. nice thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

The url query string (?xxx) should also be kept in the new url, so the whole solution should be:

```
location.href = "new_link_url" + location.search;
```