# Problems with the .click javascript when switching pages

Tags: javascript, html, css

I've got no solution to this, I've tried multiple things but it will not work! I'm new to javascript so please, someone help me out!

What I want: The animation on all pages. The #about will be later linked as about.html, so when clicked, the pages will redirect from index- to about.html. But when I click the animation will it not apply? I want to see the animation on all the pages!

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
$(".m1").click(function(){
    $(".m1").css({'color':'black'});
    $(".m2, .m3, .m4").css({'color':'white'});
    $(".active").css({'left':'0px','transform':'skewX(20deg)'});
});
$(".m2").click(function(){
    $(".m2").css({'color':'black'});
    $(".m1, .m3, .m4").css({'color':'white'});
    $(".active").css({'left':'100px','transform':'skewX(20deg)'});
});
$(".m3").click(function(){
    $(".m3").css({'color':'black'});
    $(".m1, .m2, .m4").css({'color':'white'});
    $(".active").css({'left':'359px','transform':'skewX(-20deg)'});
});
$(".m4").click(function(){
    $(".m4").css({'color':'black'});
    $(".m1, .m2, .m3").css({'color':'white'});
    $(".active").css({'left':'461px','transform':'skewX(-20deg)'});
});
});
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  background-color: #232323;
}

.main {
  position: fixed;
  top: 10px;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  z-index: 9999;
}

.menu {
  width: 100px;
  height: 30px;
  font-family: 'Stroud';
  font-size: 20px;
  color: white;
  padding: 0px;
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 30px;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: all 0.3s ease-in;
}

.active {
  width: 100px;
  height: 30px;
  background-color: white;
  position: absolute;
  top: 33px;
  left: 0px;
  transform: skewX(20deg);
  z-index: -1;
  transition: all 0.3s ease-in;
}

.m1 {
  color: black;
}

.logo {
  position: relative;
  top: initial;
  margin: 0px 30px;
}

a {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="main">
    <a href="#about"><span class="menu m1">ABOUT</span>
    <a href="#contact"><span class="menu m2">CONTACT</span>
    <a href="#home"><span class="menu logo">
        <img src="TBGFXLOGO2019NBG.png" width="100px"/>
    </span>
    <a href="#portfolio"><span class="menu m3">PORTFOLIO</span>
    <a href="#order"><span class="menu m4">ORDER</span>
    <span class="active"/>
</div>
```

Comment: I created this [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/f9cp0v46/) for you. There doesn't seem to be any issue. What's the problem exactly?

Comment: Your animation isn't going to carry over when you change it to `.html` links. Every time a page is loaded in the Browser it replaces the current state.

Comment: He could replace his page content with an iframe and have his links change the source of that iframe, but that's possibly not the best solution. It would retain the animations, but honestly I'd sacrifice form for function any day.

Comment: @JoelTrauger The white boxes behind the tabs isnt showing in jsFiddle. I want the animation over all the pages but when I go the a new *.html page the animation doesnt apply

Comment: @zfrisch you know how I can carry them over?

Comment: @TBGFX there isn't any way to link to another page and retain the animation from the current page. That's just not how the Browser works. The only way to do this would be to, as Joel Trauger pointed out, replace the content of your current page instead of hyperlinking to a new one. You could use an `iframe` or a state management library like React/Vue/etc, but your initial idea isn't possible.

Comment: @zfrisch how do I replace the content of my current page? I mean is that possible in HTML or you need PHP?

Comment: @TBGFX "You could use an `iframe` or a state management library like React, vue, etc" It is possible with HTML and JavaScript. [See here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8989247/change-src-of-iframe-and-then-reload-the-iframe) for more information on how to do this with an `iframe` if you do not want to use one of the larger JS libraries like React or Vue.

Comment: You can create a unique link for all the hyperlinks and have a function at the top of those pages, awaiting for the unique to run the animation.

Comment: @MTBthePRO you *could* but that's really bad design.